# Is it possible to extend a CSS column to the bottom of its parent

Tags: css

I'm fairly sure I know the answer to this, but I just can't find any information one way or the other.

I have an element with a `min-height` and `columns`. Browsers tend to force the columns to be even leaving a large amount of empty space at the bottom of the element. Is it possible to get the column to extend to the bottom of the element?

Here's a rough sketch of what I current have:

[image: Current effect]

And here is roughly what I would like:

[image: Desired effect]

Is this possible?

**Edit**

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/oc0z581d/) showing the markup I'm using.

Comment: What's wrong with using `height:100%`, could we have some code please?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `columns` to spread it out nice and evenly?

Comment: @jaunt - I've added a fiddle. I don't think `height:100%;` would be useful in this situation.
@somethinghere - quite possibly. They also reduce the length of the line to make the text easier to read. The client asked for them to be uneven if possible. I'm trying to find out if it can be done

Comment: you can wrap your text in a tag and then use after pseudo-el ; take a look https://jsfiddle.net/oc0z581d/5/

Comment: @maioman - I think that's exactly what I need. Stick it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a space at the bottom of the last column using an `:after` pseudo element (this space will be calculated as a part of the column and the trick is done ;) _

In the fiddle you'll find your text wrapped in a `<p>` tag with `p:after` ;

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oc0z581d/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table` property to easily achieve this

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/zr9q4mcd/

HTML:

```
<div class="display-table">
    <div class="display-tCell">
        texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext<br>texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext<br>texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext<br>texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext<br>texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext<br>texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext<br>
    </div>
    <div class="display-tCell col2">
       texttexttext<br />texttexttexttexttext
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS;

```
.display-table {
    display: table;
}
.display-tCell{
  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: gray;
}
.col2{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don't think that will help me here. I don't have control over the contents of the element, just the element itself and the styles so I don't think I can carve the contents into table columns like that.

Comment: Ah that's another question, I've just seen your fiddle. Will check it too to find a solution